# how to map two csv files in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

```
recdb
  .getCollection(SRCCOL)
  .find()
  .forEach(row => {
  //By default, put it as MISSING, if there is a MATCH, it will either show up as MATCHED/MISMATCHED
  reccol.insert(copyRow(row, {
    recStatus: ‘MISSING’,
    primaryKey: row[recCfg.primaryKey.recSrcFile]
  }));
});

recdb
  .getCollection(TSTCOL)
  .find()
  .forEach(tstRow => {
  var srcRow = recdb.getCollection(RESCOL).findOne(_.set({}, recCfg.primaryKey.recSrcFile, tstRow[recCfg.primaryKey.recTestFile]));
  if (srcRow) {
    if (srcRow.recStatus === ‘MATCHED’ || srcRow.recStatus === ‘MISMATCH’) {
      //Check for duplicates and mark them
      reccol.insert(copyRow(tstRow, {
        recStatus: ‘DUPLICATE’,
        primaryKey: tstRow[recCfg.primaryKey.recTestFile]
      }));
    } else {

      recCfg.mappings.forEach(mpg => {
        if (_.trim(srcRow[mpg.src]) != _.trim(tstRow[mpg.tst])) {
          if (!mpg.diffExpected) srcRow.recStatus = ‘MISMATCH’;
          srcRow[mpg.src] = {
            srcValue: srcRow[mpg.src],
            tstValue: tstRow[mpg.tst]
          };
        }
      });
      reccol.update(srcRow);
    }
  } else {
    //Record not found, so new record
    reccol.insert(copyRow(tstRow, {
      recStatus: ‘ADDED’,
      primaryKey: tstRow[recCfg.primaryKey.recTestFile]
    }));
  }
});

console.log(‘Generating output...’);
```

My result csv file should be MISMATCH to MATCHED while comparing two CSV file (SRC & TST) like US and United States.(US|United States) to be MATCHED

Check this image, it contains SRC , TST and RESULT tables:
[image: Check this image, it contains SRC , TST and RESULT tables.]

Comment: What is your problem with the given code? What result do you get and how does it differ form your expected result?

Comment: @t.niese   My expected result should be matched in recStatus column (recresults file) while mapping US(in src file) and United States(in tst file) .

Comment: That's what you have already said in your question. My question was, what does your code currently do, and how is your current result different to the result you expect.

Comment: @t.niese just see the ralph_recresults image, US|United States should be MATCH in my recStatus column  but my results are MISMATCH